# Volunteering for an archaeological dig

Tags: where-on-earth, volunteering, archaeology

One of my main hobbies is archaeology, but very rarely get opportunities to get my hand dirty.  What opportunities are there to travel to a location and join an archaeological dig voluntarily?

I am not fussy about where or what they are digging for, I just enjoy the experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there are tons of places where you can do that, since those sites are chronically understaffed. To give you an example of this, the Xi'an Terracotta army is staffed with less than 20 archeologists. Despite being dug out less than 10 percent. Admittedly it will be difficult in China to join in, but there are dozens of better opportunities.

- There is a [website](http://www.archaeology.co.uk/digs) for this specific topic, covering the whole UK
- There is a page covering places [all over the world](http://www.ubarchaeologist.com/Volunteer-Digs.html). While the page looks like a relic from the 80's, it's recently updated. Their [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Volunteer-Archaeological-Dig-Information-Center/305390029513622) might be easier on the eye.
- If sunny Spain and Italy are more your thing than rainy UK, [check this page](http://www.archaeospain.com/programs.htm)\
- A simple [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=join%20archaeological%20dig&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) reveals a lot more.

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to send your way some info on a medieval dig going in France in Summer of 2014.  You can read more on it here:  http://www.chateaudeleymonie.org/vacations.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of opportunities around the world. There are some digs that are very relevant.One interesitng website to check some of the most interesting and particular archaeological digs is [www.archaeobarcelona.com](http://www.archaeobarcelona.com). On this site its offered [archaeological digs and cultural tours in Barcelona](http://www.archaeobarcelona.com).

Hope it will help you! :)